# I want to install G++ on my Linux Mint but not able to do so

Tags: linux, gnu, linux-mint

I want to install g++ for using GROMACS on Linux mint. I typed the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```

It successfully installs the g++ but when I change the directory to Downloads to configure and make cmake and fftw, it (Downloads) is empty.
I have tried removing `sudo apt-get remove g++` and re-installing g++ but it shows the same result. I don't know where it is downloading g++.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/706522/g-not-installed-even-after-installing-it-sudo-apt-get-install-g

Answer (score 1):

The command `apt-get install g++` doesn't download any executables into your current directory or in the `~/Downloads/` directory.

Usually, it is installed in `/usr/bin`.

You can check for `g++` with the command `g++ --version`.

Also, you can see where it is installed with `whereis g++`.

Answer (score 0):

> The build-essential package is a reference for all the packages needed
>   to compile a Debian package. It generally includes the GCC/g++
>   compilers and libraries and some other utilities
>   https://superuser.com/a/151558

For this purpose install them with command `sudo apt install build-essential`
and it will install all the things